# MKMapView to UIImage iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimage, mkmapview

The code to render a MKMapView to an UIImage no longer works in iOS 7. It returns an empty image with nothing but the word "Legal" at the bottom and a black compass on the top right. The map itself is missing. Below is my code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(map.bounds.size);
[map.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Map is an IBOutlet that points to a MKMapView. Is there any way to render a MKMapView correctly in iOS 7?

Comment: Did you try to use `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` instead of `renderInContext:`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776288/snapshot-of-mkmapview-in-ios7) post:

You can use `MKMapSnapshotter` and grab the image from the resulting `MKMapSnapshot`. See the discussion of it [WWDC 2013](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/) session video, Putting Map Kit in Perspective.

For example:

```
MKMapSnapshotOptions *options = [[MKMapSnapshotOptions alloc] init];
options.region = self.mapView.region;
options.scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
options.size = self.mapView.frame.size;

MKMapSnapshotter *snapshotter = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions:options];
[snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
    UIImage *image = snapshot.image;
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:[self snapshotFilename] atomically:YES];
}];
```

Having said that, the `renderInContext` solution still works for me. There are notes about only doing that in the main queue in iOS7, but it still seems to work. But `MKMapSnapshotter` seems like the more appropriate solution for iOS7.

Comment: This should be a comment with a link to the other answer instead of just an exact copy of it.

Comment: This does not take into account the MKMapView overlays. How would I include the MKPolyLines and the overlays in the UIImage?

Comment: my completion block is never called