# uiimage - showing location on map

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, uiimageview

In many location based applications, clicking on a marker open a uiviewcontroller with details, in it you can see an **image** that is a subset of the map with only the specific marker on it. like this
[image]

what is the best way to implement this?

Comment: You can use MKPinAnnotationView. Try search by this word.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776288/snapshot-of-mkmapview-in-ios7