# Draw MKPointAnnotation with title in MKSnapshot image

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm trying to draw an annotation exactly as in a 'live' MapView, but then in a MKSnapshot. Why an MKSnapshot > because I want to have non-interactive MapViews in a UITableView and using images is more efficient.

I can get a pin to be drawn (though not a point as in iOS 11, the pin looks old) using MKPinAnnotationView, but also then there is no title of the annotation on the image. Using almost exactly this code: [Snapshot of MKMapView in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776288/snapshot-of-mkmapview-in-ios7).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the following steps:

- with MKMapSnapshotter you will get an image of the map without annotations
- you can retrieve the annotations from your MKMapView
- for each annotations determine its position in the coordinate space of the image
- draw a custom pin there (may look like Apple's pins)
- determine the text and size of the annotation title and draw it centered below the position of the pin

The result can look very similar to what MKMapView displays. In the attached screenshot there is a MKMapView in the upper area and an UIImageView with the resulting image in the lower area. Looks similar, doesn't it?

[image]

Here the Swift 4 code for the screenshot above:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func onSnap(_ sender: Any) {
        let options: MKMapSnapshotOptions = MKMapSnapshotOptions()
        options.region = self.mapView.region
        options.size = self.mapView.frame.size
        options.scale = UIScreen.main.scale

        let customPin = UIImage(named: "customPin.pdf")

        let snapshotter = MKMapSnapshotter(options: options)
        snapshotter.start { [weak self] (snapshot: MKMapSnapshot?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            guard error == nil, let snapshot = snapshot else { return }

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(snapshot.image.size, true, snapshot.image.scale)
            snapshot.image.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)

            let titleAttributes = self?.titleAttributes()
            for annotation in (self?.mapView.annotations)! {
                let point: CGPoint = snapshot.point(for: annotation.coordinate)
                if let customPin = customPin {
                    self?.drawPin(point: point, customPin: customPin)
                }
                if let title = annotation.title as? String {
                    self?.drawTitle(title: title,
                                    at: point,
                                    attributes: titleAttributes!)
                }
            }
            let compositeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            self?.imageView.image = compositeImage
        }
    }

    private func drawTitle(title: String,
                           at point: CGPoint,
                           attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: NSObject]) {
        let titleSize = title.size(withAttributes: attributes)
        title.draw(with: CGRect(
            x: point.x - titleSize.width / 2.0,
            y: point.y + 1,
            width: titleSize.width,
            height: titleSize.height),
                   options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                   attributes: attributes,
                   context: nil)
    }

    private func titleAttributes() -> [NSAttributedStringKey: NSObject] {
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
        let titleFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold)
        let attrs = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: titleFont,
                     NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]
        return attrs
    }

    private func drawPin(point: CGPoint, customPin: UIImage) {
        let pinPoint = CGPoint(
            x: point.x - customPin.size.width / 2.0,
            y: point.y - customPin.size.height)
        customPin.draw(at: pinPoint)
    }
}
```

**Alternative**

If you prefer to draw a MKMarkerAnnotationView (e.g. to get the nice shadow for free) you can change the `drawPin` to this:

```
private func drawPin(point: CGPoint, annotation: MKAnnotation) {
    let annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "test")
    annotationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    annotationView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
    annotationView.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(
        x: point.x - annotationView.bounds.size.width / 2.0,
        y: point.y - annotationView.bounds.size.height,
        width: annotationView.bounds.width,
        height: annotationView.bounds.height),
                                 afterScreenUpdates: true)
}
```

Don't forget to change the call to

```
self?.drawPin(point: point, annotation: annotation)
```

The result looks like this then:

[image]

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want, thanks! I'm now trying to combine your code with mine, as I draw an annotation using MKMarkerAnnotationView instead of a customPin UIImage. This gives a shadow, like in the first image of your answer :-) However the label is then off and sits in the top left of the marker. Any clue? Thanks!

Comment: @JoostvandenAkker I've added an alternative using MKMarkerAnnotationView at the end of my answer above

Comment: Glad it helped! Please consider accepting my answers (green check mark) to the two questions.

Comment: This is one of the best solutions for this task. Thanks a lot! I do however, have one question. I have not been able to locate in the code what parameter to change so that I can adjust the distance of the annotation title from the custom pin? I've tried changing the "y: point.y + 1," in the "drawTitle" method.

Comment: If you use something like 'y: point.y + 16,` in the drawTitle method, the title is displayed in the snapshot farther below the pin

Comment: @StephanSchlecht I love you