# MKMarkerAnnotationView title not getting drawn on a MKSnapShot image

Tags: swift, mkannotationview

I'm trying to draw a marker on an image (MKSnapshot) with a title, but the title is not showing up.
Does anyone has any idea why this would be the case?

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = location
    annotation.title = "TitleTest"
let pinView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "test")
    pinView.titleVisibility = MKFeatureVisibility.visible
    pinView.dragState = .none
    pinView.animatesWhenAdded = false
    pinView.canShowCallout = false
    pinView.titleVisibility = .visible
    pinView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    pinView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
    if rect!.contains(point) {
        let pinCenterOffset = pinView.centerOffset
        point.x -= pinView.bounds.size.width / 2
        point.y -= pinView.bounds.size.height / 2
        point.x += pinCenterOffset.x
        point.y += pinCenterOffset.y
    }
    pinView.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(
            x:point.x,
            y:point.y,
            width:pinView.bounds.width,
            height:pinView.bounds.height),
        afterScreenUpdates: true)
    print("Draw a marker on iOS 11")
```

This is a screenshot of my `UIImageView` with the marker, but without the title:

[image: Screenshot of my UIImageView with marker but without title]

Answer (score 0):

The title can be drawn on the snapshot below the location of the pin:

- determine the position of the annotation in the coordinate system of the image `snapshot.point(for: annotation.coordinate)`
- create the attributes for title text, you can make it similar to what Apple uses:

  ```
  private func titleAttributes() -> [NSAttributedStringKey: NSObject] {
      let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
      paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
      let titleFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold)
      let attrs = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: titleFont,
                   NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]
      return attrs
  }
  ```
- draw it right below the position of the annotation:

  ```
  private func drawTitle(title: String,
                         at point: CGPoint,
                         attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: NSObject]) {
      let titleSize = title.size(withAttributes: attributes)
      title.draw(with: CGRect(
          x: point.x - titleSize.width / 2.0,
          y: point.y + 1,
          width: titleSize.width,
          height: titleSize.height),
                 options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                 attributes: attributes,
                 context: nil)
  }
  ```

For a more complete example with code and a screenshot, see [my following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49182052/2331445) (it draws a custom pin image but the rest of the code can be used here).